# Re-evaluate parameter on each page

Tags: crystal-reports

I print out a label on our products. When an order is finished, all the data is passed to the report, which generates a generic label without quantity.

We added quantity and need the labels to print by themselves again. However the boxes vary from part to part. But a full box will always have a set quantity, and if they make more than needed, a remainder label is needed. How can I handle this in the report?

For example, one of our parts has a full box quantity of 100. But if they make 560, they would now need 5 labels with 100 quantity and one label with 60. So the  report would need to have 6 pages so they can just hit Ctrl+P and be done.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need a Shared Variable. (Assuming you already have a system in place for printing multiple pages.) Define it in the report header to be equal to the incoming parameter value. Something like:

```
Shared Number quantity;
quantity := {yourParameterHere}
```

Every time you print a page, check to see if `quantity` is greater than, or equal to, a `fullBoxCount` for the given product. If so, print a full box page and subtract `fullBoxCount` from `quantity`. Otherwise, print a remainder page. Start with a boolean formula `isFullBox`:

```
Shared Number quantity;
(quantity >= {fullBoxCount})
```

---

Then use this second formula to alter the current count:

```
Shared Number quantity;
IF ({isFullBox}) THEN quantity := quantity - {yourParameterHere}
```

Comment: If the values are different won't the pages multiply by themselves?

Comment: @Derrick Which values?

Comment: I realized that was a stupid question. Is there a way of separating them? I don't know that I would know how to make multiple pages with the same values

Comment: @Derrick What values are you referring to?